# Ignore firefox step mismatch form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, firefox

I have a number-type input field on an html form. It has a step value of 1000, because I want the user to be able to jump by 1000 when pressing the up and down arrows on the input field in the GUI.

I want the user to be able to type any value between 0 and 6000, including numbers that are not divisible by 1000, such as 1500.

However, Firefox puts a red line around the input box if the user types in a value not divisible by the step value. Is there a way to ignore this step mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the `invalid` pseudo element with CSS and hide the box shadow.

```css
input[type="number"]:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="1000">
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the red outline for exceeding min/max values, but not for being in between the step?

Comment: @NSK I don't know of a way without javascript.

Comment: I can use javascript!

Comment: @NSK just create an event listener and when it blurs or when they input test whether it's greater than the max or less than the min, if so add a class to the element.  In the class make a box shadow similar to the default. Something like `box-shadow:0 0 3px red;`.

Comment: This destroys all invalid styling, not just that relating to step mismatch.